# Cant use installed Vuetify - breaks at 40% compilation

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuetify.js

When i compile my Vue project it stops at 40% and doesnt compile any further.

I already know that it has to do with the use of vuetify in this component.

```
<template>
  <v-form>
    <v-text-field placeholder="Username" solo></v-text-field>
    <v-text-field placeholder="Password" type="password" solo></v-text-field>
  </v-form>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import Component from 'vue-class-component';

@Component
export default class Login extends Vue {

}
</script>

<style scoped>
  v-form {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
</style>
```

i dont use vuetify in any other component.

I followed the installation guide for vuetify with webpack. https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/#webpack-install

I have Vuetify 2.5.14 (also didnt work with 2.5.10), Webpack 4.46.0, Vue 2.6.14, using prerendering SPA Plugin (if that matters...).

Heres my configuration:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "prerender-spa-plugin": "^3.4.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-class-component": "^7.2.3",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^9.1.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
    "vuetify": "^2.5.14",
    "vuex": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.18.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.18.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-standard": "^5.1.2",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^7.0.0",
    "deepmerge": "^4.2.2",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "sass": "^1.32.13",
    "sass-loader": "^10.2.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.4.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.7.0"
  }
}
```

node_modules/vuetify-loader/dev4/webpack-config.js

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin')
const VuetifyLoaderPlugin = require('vuetify-loader/lib/plugin')
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin

const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'

function sassLoaderOptions (indentedSyntax = false) {
  return {
    implementation: require('sass'),
    additionalData: `@import "~@/_variables.scss"` + (indentedSyntax ? '' : ';'),
    sassOptions: { indentedSyntax },
  }
}

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  mode: isProd ? 'production' : 'development',
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s(c|a)ss$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            // Requires sass-loader@^7.0.0
            options: {
              implementation: require('sass'),
              indentedSyntax: true // optional
            },
            // Requires >= sass-loader@^8.0.0
            options: {
              implementation: require('sass'),
              sassOptions: {
                indentedSyntax: true // optional
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(vuetify)\/)/
      },
      {
        test: /\.sass$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          { loader: 'css-loader',  options: { esModule: false } },
          { loader: 'sass-loader', options: sassLoaderOptions(true) }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          { loader: 'css-loader',  options: { esModule: false } },
          { loader: 'sass-loader', options: sassLoaderOptions() }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: { limit: 1024 }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js'),
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
  },
  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    new VuetifyLoaderPlugin({
      progressiveImages: true
    }),
    new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
      analyzerMode: 'static',
      openAnalyzer: false
    })
  ],
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
    overlay: true
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  optimization: {
    concatenateModules: false
  }
}

if (isProd) {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    })
  ])
}
```

vuetify.ts

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib/framework'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Vuetify({
})
```

main.ts

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Does anyone know why my compilation breaks at 40% and what it has to do with my setup, especially regarding vuetify?